# FlatList scroll after adding new element

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using [FlatList](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/flatlist.html#flatlist) component of ReactNative and it is working perfectly. Now i want to scroll it to bottom whenever user enters new element/comment.

```
<FlatList style={styles.commentList}
    data={commentList}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    renderItem={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
/>
```

Now whenever user enters new comment, commentList will be updated and FlatList also gets refresh, but i want to be scroll to the bottom so that user can read latest comment posted.

Comment: Did you try scrollToIndex? Check the docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex

Comment: @Srijith yes i have tried that also `this.commentRef.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 10 })` but somehow that also didn't work.

Comment: It will be great if you can share a snack here https://snack.expo.io/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: 
Its not my solution, but i got working using this method.

https://exp.host/@xavieramoros/snack-SyN4FJikz
source code:
https://github.com/xavieramoros/flatlist-initialScrollIndexIssue/blob/master/App.js
Expo 22 - RN 0.49

A great thanks to https://expo.io/@xavieramoros

**Edited**: If you just want to scroll to bottom then scrollToEnd (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoend) is available in new RN. 
use it like

```
<FlatList
        ref={ (ref) => { this.flatList = ref; }}
        data={this.data}
        renderItem={ this.renderItem }
        keyExtractor={ this.keyExtractor}
        onScroll={ this.scrollToEnd}
      />
    ......
```

and in your method

```
scrollToEnd = () => {
    const wait = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    wait.then( () => {
        this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    });
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I have used the answer to the link to some extent myself , but since the context can be different in each question, I just posted the whole answer ( the link ).
As for your case, make sure you have getItemLayout implemented for variable index height. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex)

And Also the question is really general , if you want some specific answer then please post a full question with more code! Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try FlatList with inverted prop as true. (might as well reverse the data array) 
Since flatlist is inverted, the new data is added on the first position, and because of this update flatlist automatically scrolls to first position, which in your case is the bottom location

Comment: Will it show recent/new elements at the end or first element?